# how to convert Glib::ustring to std::string?

Tags: c++, glib

I cannot find any example on how to do this

actually I just want to check if a ustring is equal to a constant string but it does not work

```
Glib::ustring somestring...
if(somestring=="test")
  always returns true
```

thanks

Comment: Where is `std::string` involved in your example?

Comment: as comparing with a constant did not work, I tried somestring.raw()==std::string("test")

Comment: And did it work then?

Comment: well no, I would not be here asking how to do it :-)

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] as usual please.

Comment: everything is there, I want to do a simple comparison, the xml parser I use, uses these ustring and I cant find any decent example...I am better off using a xml parser that dont use fancy b..sh.. strings that do utf16 but cant be compared with a simpe operator or at least provide a working function to convert to utf8 or so...

thanks anyway

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. That is - when using real, compilable code, i.e. the kind that you should have included in your question. The `operator==` successfully returns `true` when the strings are equal, and returns `false` when they differ. If `ustring` had a problem this serious, it would have been noticed and fixed as soon as it arose.

Comment: Also, `Glib::ustring` has nothing to do with UTF-16, otherwise it could not internally use an `std::basic_string<char>`. It specifically exists to manage UTF-8 strings - a noble goal, since the Standard Library so egregiously lacks _any_ support for that - so why would you need to "convert to utf8 or so"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is

```
std::string(someustring) == "test"
```

strange as Glib::ustring has 99% the same interface as std::string

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have any `std::string` in it but if you want to compare a `Glib::ustring` with a string literal the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html) says there is a compare()` method for that.

Comment: there is virtualy no documentation on that Glib class

Comment: ok finaly I think it is working, developing with geany under linux is a terrible experience

Comment: "finaly I think it is working". How? What did you do to fix it? There should not have been any problem in the first place, as `Glib::ustring` provides an `operator==`. If that did not work, you should have filed a bug upstream.

Comment: Anyway, in `ustring`, glancing at the header will show that `operator==` just delegates to `compare()`. The latter exists to do collated comparison. Both achieve the same thing, and both work fine as far as I can see.